# PHP PDO Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Tags: php, pdo

I'm sure it's obvious, but I can't spot what's wrong with the code below:

```
$sSQl="SELECT nDocumentID, sFilename, sDescription 
　　　　FROM tCompanyDocuments 
　　　　WHERE nCompanyID=:nCompanyID AND sDocumentType='I' ORDER BY nDisplayOrder";
$objQuery=$objConn->prepare($sSQL);
$objQuery->bindParam(':nCompanyID', $arrResult['nCompanyID']);
if ($objQuery->execute()) {
    $arrTemp=$objQuery->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if (sizeof($arrTemp)>0) {
        foreach ($arrTemp as $objRow) {
            //do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

The error message is "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens' in {filename}" and the line referenced is $objQuery->execute()

I've confirmed that `$arrResult['nCompanyID']` is populated - what can't I see?

Thanks

Comment: first separate with spaces the `=` and the col/token: `nCompanyID = :nCompanyID`, then you can try binValue instead http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php

Comment: Thanks Royal BG - but I've tried both of those suggestions - nothing changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How did you verify the $arrResult['nCompanyID'] ?
The query seems to run fine and it returns result. I guess it's the $arrResult['nCompanyID'] that is empty.

Comment: Thanks lu - when I output this just before the query, it does show the expected number (16)...

Comment: Also, in addition - there is sSQ[L] and sSQ[l]. Maybe nothing important but ... try to change the sSQL to uppercase "L"

Comment: That's it - PHP is case sensitive so I was loading the wrong query! Thanks Lu

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$sSQl="SELECT nDocumentID, sFilename, sDescription 
　　　　FROM tCompanyDocuments 
　　　　WHERE nCompanyID = :nCompanyID AND sDocumentType='I' ORDER BY nDisplayOrder";
```

if nCompanyID is integer type then:

```
 $objQuery->bindParam(':nCompanyID', $arrResult['nCompanyID'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

or

```
 $objQuery->bindParam(':nCompanyID', $arrResult['nCompanyID'], PDO::PARAM_STR,Length of string);
```

[See details](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php)

Comment: Thanks Awlad - but I've tried adding PDO::PARAM_INT and nothing changes.

Comment: It seems that you have skip some other php script. there should not be anything wrong here.